# UIPopover get exact position on screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uipopover, uipopoverbackgroundview

I have an iPad app in which I show an `UIPopover` view. I want to set the background of the popover depending on its position on the screen. Is it possible to get the exact position of the `UIPopover` relative to the screen?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    if ([myPopOverController isPopoverVisible]) {

        CGPoint myPopOverPosition = [myPopOverController.contentViewController.view
                      convertPoint:myPopOverController.contentViewController.view.frame.origin
                      toView:mainTopView];

        //If you set toView to nil then it will consider as the window or you could specify as yourappDelegate.window


    }
```